# Prove that if 5 does not divide an integer $m$, then $m^{2}\equiv1\mod 5$ or $m^{2}\equiv-1\mod 5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I wanted to do something like if $5$ does not divide $m$ then $m \ne5x,$ where x is an integer, so $m = 5x-1$ or $5x+1$, but I realized you could add or subtract any constant between $1$ and $4$ and it would work. So I don't really know how to go about this.

Comment: I'm guessing you copied the problem wrong. Perhaps you mean $m^2$ instead of $m$ in both congruences?

Comment: A correct statement similar to yours would be "If $5$ does not divide the integer $m$, then $m^2\equiv 1\,(\mathrm{mod}\, 5)$  or $m^2\equiv -1\,(\mathrm{mod}\, 5)$."

Comment: right sorry I have corrected it

Comment: $\large \bmod 5\!:\,\ n\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, n\equiv \pm1,\pm2\,\Rightarrow\, n^2\equiv \pm 1\ \ \ $

Comment: since $5$ is prime, Fermat's little theorem says if $5\nmid m$ then $m^4\equiv1\pmod5$, which means $m^2\equiv\pm1\pmod5$

Comment: "but I realized you could add or minus any constant between 1 and 4 and it'd work. So I don't really know how to go about this."  You'd go about it by adding or minus any constant beween 1 and 4.  There are only four of them so it shouldn't take more than a few seconds.

Comment: Because $5x-1,2,3,4 =  5(x-1) + 4,2,3,1$ you don't have to do plus *AND* minus.  just plus *OR* minus  And as $big^2=bigbig$ and $5x + 4,3 = 5(x+1)-1,2$ you only have to do $5x +1,2,-1,-2$ which will be easier and smaller.  $(5x\pm 1,2)^2 = 5x^2 \pm 2,4*5x + 1,4$ so $m^2 = 5J +1,4=5K+1,-1$.  That's all you have to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Modulo $5$, an integer which isn't a multiple of $5$ is either $1,2,3$ or $4$. What happens if you square each and look at the remainder when you divide by $5$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $5$ is prime, Fermat's little theorem says that, if $5\nmid m$ then $m^4\equiv1 \pmod 5$,

i.e., $m^4-1=(m^2+1)(m^2-1)\equiv0\pmod5$.

Again since $5$ is prime, this means that $m^2+1\equiv0\pmod5\;$ or $\;m^2-1\equiv0\pmod5$;

i.e., $m^2\equiv-1\pmod5\;$ or $\;m^2\equiv 1\pmod5$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you had the right idea.  If $5\not \mid m$ then

$m = 5x +1; 5x+2; 5x+3; 5x+4$ so $m^2 = 25x^2 + 10x + 1=5(5x^2 + 2x)) + 1; 25x^2 + 20x+ 4=5(5x^2 + 4x +1)-1; 25x^2 + 30x + 9=5(5x^2 + 6x + 2) -1;$ or $25x^2 + 40x + 16=5(5x^2 + 8x + 3) + 1$.

Or more simply:

$m\equiv 1,2,3,4 \pmod 5$ and $m^2 \equiv 1,2^2,3^2, 4^2 \equiv 1,4,9,16\equiv 1,4,4,1 \equiv 1,-1,-1,1 \pmod 5$ and that's that.

You can make it slicker and realize that for all $m \in \mathbb Z$ that $m \equiv 0, \pm 1, \pm 2$ and if $5\not \mid m$ that $m\equiv \pm 1, \pm 2\pmod 5$ so $m^2 \equiv (\pm 1)^2, (\pm 2)^2\equiv 1^2,2^2, \equiv 1,4\equiv 1 ,-1\pmod 5$.

You have to comfortable with knowing that for any $m \in \mathbb Z$ if $n =2k$ is even then $-k+1, -k+2,...., -1, 0,1, .....,k$ and if $n=2k+1$ is odd then $-k,-k+1, ....,-1,0,1,....,k$ are complete residue class $\mod n$ and you should be utterly convinced that if $m\equiv a\pmod n$ then $m^j \equiv a^j \pmod n$ for every $j$.

[Just because it *never* hurts:

[If $m \equiv a \pmod n$ then $m = a + kn$ for some integer $k$.

[ So $m^j = (a+kn)^j = a^j + \sum_{v=1}^j n^v*a^{j-v}*{j\choose v}=$

[ $a^j + n*\sum_{v=1}^j n^{v-1}*a^{j-v}*{j\choose v}$.  so $m^j\equiv a^j \pmod n$.

[One should *never* *ever* not be able to rattle this result and proof of the top of there head when rustled for a sound sleep and discover the house is burning around you.   It should be *utterly* automatic.